# How Java Operator Precedence exactly work?

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I want to ask something simple.

I provide a very simple calculation example that I receive a result different than my expectations. 
Could somebody explain which step I made wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       int x  =1;
       int y = 101;
       int a = 2;


       int z =  ++y + y * a << 3 *2 * ++x + (x+=2);
       /*
       Step 1 int z =  ++y + y * a << 3 *2 * ++x + (3);
       Step 2 int z =  102 + 102 * 2 << 3 *2 * 4 + (3);
       Step 3 int z =  102 + 204 << 24 + (3);
       Step 4 int z =  306 << 27;
       Expected:41,070,624,768‬
        */

       System.out.println(z);
       //Actual: 20,054,016
   }
```

Comment: read official documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bit-shift operators](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) have a lower precedence than additive operators, which have a lower precedence than multiplicative operators, which have a lower precedence than increment/decrement operators.  Also notice that variables are evaluated left-to-right regardless of the precedence of the operators between them.

```
int z =  ++y + y * a << 3 *2 * ++x + (x+=2);
```

First, do increments.

```
102 + 102 * 2 << 3 * 2 * 2 + 4
```

Next, do multiplication.

```
102 + 204 << 12 + 4
```

Then do addition.

```
306 << 16
```

The bit shift results in `20054016`.

It looks like you erred when evaluating the expressions with `x` in them on the far right.

Comment: @rgettmann But Why ?!!!
It looks to me like you give higher precedence to ++x prior than (x+=2). I believe anything in brackets should be calculated first ? So x becomes 3. And ++x becomes 4. Should'n brackets be first ?

Comment: As I stated in my answer, evaluations of variables occur before any operators are applied.  The expression `++x` occurs first, yielding `2` and setting `x` to `2`.  Then the `x` in `(x += 2)` is evaluated, yielding `2`.  Then operators are evaluated, first `()` which has the highest priority, making `(x += 2)` evaluated next, yielding `4` and setting `x` to `4`.

Comment: I just did it (accepting the asnwer) @rgettmann. One more time thanks for your time on it !